# Getting wrong hours when Convert date without time to Milliseconds using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am trying to convert Date to Milliseconds without timestamp .

```
   final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
   sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
   Date dateObj = sdf.parse(date);
   System.out.println ("Milliseconds ="+ dateObj.getTime()) ;
```

INPUT : 
`2019-05-08`

OUTPUT :
`Milliseconds = 1557253800000 // is 2019-05-08T12:00:00 not 2019-05-08T00:00:00`

I want to Convert `"2019-05-08"` to milliseconds of `2019-05-08T00:00:00` ? Any solution for this .

Comment: 1) use `java.time`, 2) You parse your date in the time zone `Asia/Kolkata` so this is expected.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`1557253800000` corresponds to `2019-05-07T18:30:00Z`. As the timezone Asia/Kolkata is 5:30 hours ahead of UTC this corresponds to `2019-05-08T00:00:00+0530`. That is your code is working as expected.

As mentioned by @Lino in the comments with Java 8 the new `java.time` classes should be used instead of `java.util.Date`. This would be the corresponding code using the new `java.time` API:

```
String str = "2019-05-08";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli()); // will output 1557253800000

zonedDateTime = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli()); // will output 1557273600000
```

Comment: Maybe worth adding that the `java.time` "solution" to the question is `LocalDate.parse("2019-05-08")`.

Comment: @assylias thanks for pointing this out. I updated the code example to use `LocalDate` instead of `LocalDateTime`